# Negative binomial regression of month trend

Tags: r

I read a paper about negative binomial regression:"We modelled the number of Ecoli bloodstream infections and E coli UTIs per month using negative-binomial regression (incorporating overdispersion), assuming the same underlying population(no offset)." The figure as the followings
[image]

I also have a set of data, want to figure the infection like the figure with month/year, how can I do that? thank you very much

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 
2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2013, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 
2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 
2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2015), Month = c(1, 2, 3, 
4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
11, 12, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12), Incidence = c(2.25538216197745, 
3.49502862307924, 2.76311704439615, 2.9836483329794, 3.09375, 
3.0368028900429, 3.82920688208141, 3.9154960734432, 3.33517393705135, 
3.54593329432417, 3.27586206896552, 3.25655281969817, 3.35912052117264, 
3.21672101986362, 2.78237182605312, 2.58435732397113, 2.72516428295323, 
3.1227603153476, 2.6300688599847, 2.66324718879463, 2.62653374233129, 
2.45256358498183, 2.39520958083832, 3.58683926645092, 3.41995942421022, 
3.61001317523057, 2.62718158187895, 2.86944045911047, 2.77978993118435, 
2.89282762420792, 2.69410829432029, 3.22232223222322, 3.39818882811799, 
3.36725958337297, 2.90030211480363, 3.20789124668435), Inpatient = c(8779, 
6638, 9663, 9418, 9600, 8858, 9532, 9041, 9055, 8545, 9280, 10072, 
9824, 6746, 10279, 10254, 10348, 9767, 10456, 10138, 10432, 9908, 
9853, 11124, 10351, 7590, 10772, 11152, 11044, 10889, 11321, 
11110, 11153, 10513, 11585, 12064), infection = c(198, 232, 267, 
281, 297, 269, 365, 354, 302, 303, 304, 328, 330, 217, 286, 265, 
282, 305, 275, 270, 274, 243, 236, 399, 354, 274, 283, 320, 307, 
315, 305, 358, 379, 354, 336, 387)), row.names = c(NA, -36L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

reference:
Vihta K D, Stoesser N, Llewelyn M J, et al. Trends over time in Escherichia coli bloodstream infections, urinary tract infections, and antibiotic susceptibilities in Oxfordshire, UK, 1998–2016: a study of electronic health records[J]. The Lancet Infectious Diseases, 2018, 18(10): 1138-1149.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please use the [appropriate formatting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/371738) in the future if you ask a question, this time we did it for you. In addition, this is quite broad asking. What specific coding problem do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the data above, one can do the following:

```
library(MASS) # for function glm.nb
library(ggplot2)
library(broom) # for tidy model outputs
```

Create a date, to make plotting easy

```
df$t <- as.Date(paste("01", df$Month, df$Year, sep = "-"), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
```

Plot the data. `geom_smooth` adds the trend line and confidence intervals, using the date as the predictor.

```
p <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = t, y = infection)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_smooth(method = "glm.nb")
p
```

To perform the regression, set the count of infections as the dependent variable and the nth month as the independent variable, below `month_as_integer`.

```
df$month_as_integer <- seq_along(df$Month)
m1 <- glm.nb(infection ~ month_as_integer, data = df)
```

using `tidy` from the broom package, one can get the estimate and confidence intervals as a data frame.

```
out1 <- as.data.frame(tidy(m1, exponentiate = TRUE, conf.int = TRUE) )

out1
              term  estimate   std.error  statistic     p.value   conf.low  conf.high
1      (Intercept) 264.44399 0.048006493 116.184897 0.000000000 240.943378 290.556355
2 month_as_integer   1.00697 0.002250993   3.085763 0.002030303   1.002569   1.011394
```

Comment: I'm not sure an additive model with month and year is what the OP really wants (whether they know it or not); I would instead construct a numeric date variable that gives time in years since the first observation time, and regress on that (if the OP also wants to include seasonal effects, that's another question ...)

Comment: Thanks Ben. Given that the original paper modelled by month, should the time variable in fact be the count of months since first observation and should the first observation be 1 or 0?

Comment: Yes, probably.  I would use t=0 at the first observation, but don't think it matters much.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's very useful.