# zero inflated Poisson GLM in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, glm

my data frame is as follows:

```
> head(dataset_presence)
        Date  Int_Bk    ui_avg     ui_sd dcalls sep2 presence  ui_lag02
5  2016-01-12 -9044.3  1.136538  4.502629     41    2        1        NA
6  2016-01-13 -8761.7 -1.841046 12.318525     17    0        1        NA
7  2016-01-14 -8930.4  3.887893 12.243056      0    1        1  1.136538
8  2016-01-15 -9267.8 10.980019  7.707563      0    0        0 -1.841046
9  2016-01-16 -9092.2 19.544113 15.408313      0    0        0  3.887893
10 2016-01-17 -9146.0  1.304933 13.310565      0    0        0 10.980019
```

I want to run a zero inflated GLM for dcalls ~ ui_avg and then use ggplot to show the response curve.
Here is the code I use for the non-zero inflated GLM (which works fine):

```
p7 <- ggplot(dataset_presence, aes(ui_avg, dcalls)) +
    geom_point() +
    geom_smooth(method="glm", method.args = list(family = poisson(link = "log")))
```

Can anyone help me with the code I would use for a zero-inflated GLM?

Thank you.

Comment: This might be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827835/negative-binomial-regression-of-month-trend

Comment: It seems you're asking for a way to fit the ZIP model directly within the call to `geom_smooth()`... I don't think you can do that. You'll have to fit the model separately, and then plug the predictions into your plot...